# How to bind NHibernate ISessionFactory with Caliburn.MIcro Simple IOC Container

Tags: nhibernate, ioc-container, caliburn.micro

I only have experience with Ninject IOC.

I am converting to Caliburn.Micro for WPF development. Love it so far. I've started with their MEF sample and love the flexibility.

Can't figure out how to bind this working code from Ninject into a Caliburn.Micros SimpleContainer.

```
kernel.Bind<Func<ISessionFactory>>().ToMethod(c =>
    () => Fluently.Configure()
          .Database(MsSqlCeConfiguration.Standard
          .Dialect<ImpactMsSqlCeDialect>()
          .ConnectionString(String.Format("Data Source={0}", "c:\\AppDB.sdf")))
          .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ChildMap>())//.ExportTo(@"C:\fnh\"))
          .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ClassMap>()) //.ExportTo(@"C:\fnh\")
          .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ClassTypeMap>())
          .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<CustomerMap>())
          .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<EmployeeMap>())
          .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<PunchcardMap>())
          .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<PunchcardTypeMap>())
          .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<PunchMap>())
          //.ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true))
#if DEBUG
          .BuildConfiguration().SetInterceptor(new SqlStatementInterceptor())
#else
#endif
          .BuildSessionFactory()).InSingletonScope();
```

I'm lost, so I don't even want to offer any of the attempts I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code it looks like you are trying to register a factory method or factory in the form a `Func<>` delegate.

Factories or factory methods can be registered with `SimpleContainer` using the `Handler<TService>(Func<SimpleContainer, object> handler)` extension method as noted by the **[documentation](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Simple%20IoC%20Container&referringTitle=Documentation)** of the SimpleContainer class.

As you can see, with this method you can register a `Func<>` which accepts the container itself in case you want to pull any dependencies that might participate in building the instance implementation of the service type you passed to `Hander<TService>`.

So in your situation your code could become something like the following:

```
SimpleContainer _container = new SimpleContainer();
_container.Handler<Func<ISessionFactory>>( diContainer => {
    Fluently.Configure()
      .Database(MsSqlCeConfiguration.Standard
      .Dialect<ImpactMsSqlCeDialect>()
      .ConnectionString(String.Format("Data Source={0}", "c:\\AppDB.sdf")))
      .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ChildMap>())//.ExportTo(@"C:\fnh\"))
      .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ClassMap>()) //.ExportTo(@"C:\fnh\")
      .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ClassTypeMap>())
      .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<CustomerMap>())
      .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<EmployeeMap>())
      .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<PunchcardMap>())
      .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<PunchcardTypeMap>())
      .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<PunchMap>())

      // HERE YOU SHOULD RETURN A Func<ISessionFactory>
}
```

If this doesn't work for you please let me know.